# How to send background color data of a button to server using socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to send the current background color of a button over to the server that will change the state of a LED depending on the color of the button but no data has been received by the server.

```js
var app = require('http').createServer(handler), 
    io = require('/home/pi/node_modules/socket.io').listen(app), 
    fs = require('fs'),
    firmata = require('/home/pi/node_modules/firmata'),
    board = new firmata.Board('/dev/ttyACM0', arduinoReady);
 
var ledPin = 13;
 
function arduinoReady(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Firmware: ' + board.firmware.name 
      + '-' + board.firmware.version.major 
      + '.' + board.firmware.version.minor);
 
    var ledOn = true;
    board.pinMode(ledPin, board.MODES.OUTPUT);
}
 
app.listen(8080);
console.log("Listening on http://raspberrypi:8080...");
 
// directs page requests to html files
 
function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/jie.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading jie.html');
    }
 
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}
 
// this handles socket.io comm from html files
 
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('connected...');
 
    socket.on('color', function(data) {
        if (data == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
            console.log('+');
            board.digitalWrite(ledPin, board.HIGH);
            socket.broadcast.send("let there be light!");
  }
        
        if (data == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)' {
            console.log('-');
            board.digitalWrite(ledPin, board.LOW);
            socket.broadcast.send("who turned out the light?");
        }
        return;
    });
 
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        socket.send('disconnected...');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
 <style>
#switchButton{
 background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
 
 </style>
        <title>example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
                <button id="switchButton" class="button">turn on</button>
               
            </p>
        </div>    
        <div>
            <ul id="messages">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="/home/pi/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/home/pi/onjie/ion.js"></script>
        
        <script>
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    var confirmationMessage = 'It looks like you have been editing something. '
                            + 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.';

    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; 

    return confirmationMessage; 
});
   
            $(function(){
    
   
                var socket = io.connect('http://raspberrypi:8080');
                
                socket.on('connect', function() {
                    $('#messages').append('<li>Connected to the server.</li>');            
                });
                
                socket.on('message', function(color) {    
                    $('#messages').append('<li>' + color + '</li>');
                });
                
                socket.on('disconnect', function() {
                    $('#messages').append('<li>Disconnected from the server.</li>');            
                });
                
                $('#switchButton').bind('click', function() {
                    var color = $("#switchButton").css("background-color");
                    socket.send(color);
                    $('#color').append('<li>me: ' + color + '</li>');

                    if (color == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)')
                        $("#switchButton").css("background-color", "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
                    else 
                        $("#switchButton").css("background-color", "rgb(0, 0, 0)");
                        console.log(color);
                });   
                 
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there something wrong on how the data is sent or received? I tried using the same method but with button texts and it worked but no luck with this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're client/browser code needs to send the color data with an "event name" - in your case, that would be "color".

Your server code is currently setup to listening for any "color" messages, ie:

```
socket.on('color', function(data) {
    /* 
    Server side logic to handle "color" messages
    */
});
```

Your client code however is not sending color data on that message "channel". You should find that adding `'color'` as the first parameter to `.send()` will fix the issue as shown:

```
$('#switchButton').bind('click', function() {  

   var color = $("#switchButton").css("background-color");
   socket.send('color', color); /* <-- include 'color' to send "color message" 
                                       with color data  */

   /* Remaining click code for #switchButton here */
})
```

In terms of the way in which your're sending the actual color data to the server, that should be fine however you may find the `rgb( .. )` approach makes your code sensitive to irregularly placed white spaces, etc.

As a suggestion to protect against such issues, consider updating your client and server code to use `red` rather than `rgb(255, 0, 0)`, and `black` rather than `rgb(0, 0, 0)` (note that this is supported by CSS also)